# What is Monero Meta?

Tags: discussion

I saw it in my profile and went to check it out but don't understand what the difference is with here. It also doesn't allow Monero tags.

Comment: Not a question about Monero, but about SE. Belongs to meta :)

Comment: Moved it to meta. ;)

Comment: @5chdn Actually, since this is in fact a question about Monero Meta, it belongs on Monera Meta Meta. Please migrate it there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a stackexhange thing. Every site has the corresponding meta. It's a place to talk about how the main site is moderated, what kind of questions are off-topic, tags policy etc.

Answer (score 4):

meta to me just means 'data about data itself'. so monero meta is discussion about the page itself, a deeper level of participation if you will :)