# When the help center says meta is for reporting bugs, does it mean bugs in the StackExchange page or bugs in monero software?

Tags: discussion

The help center says meta is for reporting bugs. Per an answer to this [question](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108/what-is-monero-meta), it seems like the bugs to be reported should be with the StackExchange monero page itself and not the monero software. Which would mean there is some sort of programming for StackExchange pages separate from the StackExchange platform itself. I do not know much about StackExchange, so is this reasoning accurate?

If I am experiencing what appears to be a bug in the actual monero (monerod) software, does this mean the best/only place for me to report this bug is in the github page and not the StackExchange meta page?

(the bug is detailed by my question [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2742/segmentation-fault-problem-when-running-monerod-in-whonix))

Answer (score 3):

> When the help center says meta is for reporting bugs, does it mean bugs in the StackExchange page or bugs in Monero software?

Bugs relating to Stack Exchange itself should be handled on [meta](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). Bugs about Monero software should be asked about on the primary [Monero SE](https://monero.stackexchange.com/) site.

I moved this question to [meta](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) because you are asking about how Stack Exchange works. You were correct to ask your [segmentation fault problem when running monerod in whonix](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2742/segmentation-fault-problem-when-running-monerod-in-whonix) question on [Monero SE](https://monero.stackexchange.com/), because it was about a bug you experienced when running Monero software.